# unclickable checkbox - css only

Tags: css, checkbox

I have been working on customize a checkbox. I am not able to unclick the checkbox since I modified to be rounded.
What's wrong with the following codes?

In Html,

```
<div class="checkbox-circle">
    <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" checked />
    <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.checkbox-circle input[type="checkbox"] {
   display: none;
}
.checkbox-circle label {
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 25px;
   margin-right: 12px;
}
.checkbox-circle label:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;  
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkbox-circle input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
   font-size: 13px;
   color: #5bc0de;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 11px;
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   content: "\e013";
```

}

It's showing as what I wanted but not clickable at all. Thanks in advance -css only.

Comment: [demo](http://www.bootply.com/mFm95fnjBq) - works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact you are using `display:none` to hide the checkbox and it doesn't work on all environments.

I suggest you a safer implementation with this code:

```
.checkbox-circle input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0; // instead of display:none
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 2; // or above
}
```

the concept is having the user clicking a real -invisible- checkbox and propagating the style using the `:checked` selector as you did.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't modify the checkbox; you hid the checkbox and added your own checkbox-like element. Because the checkbox is hidden you can't click on it, therefore the state won't change.

If you want to do it this way then you will need to add some Javascript to link the state of the hidden checkbox to your custom checkbox element and to change the state when your element is clicked on.

**Edit:** Actually I'm wrong about this, I forgot that clicking on the label can toggle the state of the checkbox, oops. It still might be easier to use Javascript than to hide the checkbox though.

Comment: It seems it's working on your computer. I want to sort this out with css only. Thanks.

Comment: Which browser and operating system are you using? It's probably an issue with that browser.

Comment: I am using Chrome and Windows 7.It's not clicking on Chrome, IE, Firefox.

Comment: This is a simple mistake leaving out 'for' in the label tag. Solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with CSS :

.noclick {pointer-events:none;}

<input class="noclick type="checkbox">